# Integration of urdf_parser in non-ROS software using CMake

Tags: ros, urdf, cmake, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to extend my library [RBDL](http://rbdl.bitbucket.org) (the Rigid Body Dynamics Library) to allow loading of models described by urdf. For this I would like to use the existing urdf_parser from ROS. As a build system I use CMake.

Normally I would create some FindXXX.cmake scripts and search for the include directories and libraries using CMake, however the dependencies for the urdf parser and model seem to be more involved than would be feasible for this approach.

What would be the best practice to find and link against the ROS urdf libraries?

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32193/integration-of-urdf_parser-in-non-ros-software-using-cmake/) by [Martin Felis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2206/martin-felis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Felis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2206/martin-felis/) on 2012-04-19**:
Hi Thomas! I'm fine, thanks ;D. The code to load urdf models would just be an optional addon to RBDL and therefore I do not see a problem making that addon dependent on ROS. I guess in that way it makes more sense to use the first approach. But, if there is interest I might add RBDL to ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Martin,
I hope you are doing well !

You have two different ways of achieving what you want:

1. detect `urdf_parser` using `rospack`. This tool will give you the compilation and linking flags required to use `urdf_parser`. The main drawback I see is that RBDL will rely on ROS which is a *huge* dependency.
   To do so, you can use this CMake macro: https://github.com/jrl-umi3218/jrl-cmakemodules/blob/master/ros.cmake
   ...and adapt it to your needs.
2. the second way is more "traditional". Numerous libraries have been integrated into ROS using this scheme. It would be to create a ROS rbld stack containing two packages: one is `rbdl` a ROS package wrapping your library and the second would be `rbdl_bridge` another ROS package containing the code required to load a URDF model.
   In this case, as rbdl_bridge is part of ROS, you can directly depend on `urdf_parser` using the `manifest.xml` file.

Personnally, I would go for the second solution which is more modular, avoid coupling tightly RBDL to ROS and would allow you to properly document the ROS integration on the ROS wiki. You could as well release your stack and obtain a Debian package of the RBDL ROS stack which can be installed using `apt-get`.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`urdfdom` ([urdfdom](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom) + [urdfdom_headers](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers)) is now a separate project that only depends on `Boost`, `console_bridge` and `tinyxml`.

This removes the ROS dependency and makes it easier for non-ROS projects to use URDF files. With CMake, you can find `urdfdom` with the usual methods (e.g. `pkg-config`).

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2